# querying a JSOn object in separate columns from Postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with column type as `json`.

```
select request_id,cast(job_info as varchar)  from requests_table where cast(job_id as varchar) like '%4665-b583-3b92218db8ce%';
```

Here `job_info` and `job_id` are the `json` type column.

It yield me data like this:

```
          request_id   |                 job_info
--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 f373085d-0124a161b2d7 | ["test-cluster", "test-cluster-id-11111"]
(1 row)
```

I am expecting job_info data should get retrieved as two separate column.

```
f373085d-0124a161b2d7,test-cluster,test-cluster-id-11111
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract each array element using the`->>` operator:

```
select request_id,
       job_info ->> 0 as cluster_1, 
       job_info ->> 1 as cluster_2
from requests_table 
where cast(job_id as varchar) like '%4665-b583-3b92218db8ce%'
```

Comment: Thanks.. Perfect!. I was doing something like this. Thanks again

Comment: what if my job_id has multiple values  like job_info and I have to look specific value using where clause.. let me know if it has to be another question. Thanks

Comment: yes, please ask a new question.